# How do you query a RethinkDB server for its version?

Tags: rethinkdb

Suppose I've connected to a RethinkDB server's web UI and I'd like to find out what version is running under the hood. Is there a way (in the Data Explorer?) to query for the version number, e.g. 1.13.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Admin UI if you click on the "gear" icon in the top-right of the navbar then a notification bar slides down. In the far-right of that bar is a version number print-out.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't yet a programmatic way -- as Cody mentioned, clicking the gear icon in the web UI will show the version number. I opened a proposal on GitHub to add r.version() to a future version of RethinkDB: https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/2698

Answer (score 1):

If you use the data explorer, you can run

```
r.expr(VERSION)
```

Note that this work **ONLY** in the data explorer. There is a global `VERSION` variable in the js files (that we use when you click on the gear icon that Cody mentioned).

That should work anywhere as long as the web interface is enabled (supposing that you started the web interface on the default 8080 port)

```
r.http('http://localhost:8080/ajax/stat').do(function(doc) {
   return doc(doc.keys().nth(0))('proc')('version')
})
```

It's kind of hack-ish though, but it works.